# Concatenate number into a list of text in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to concatenate some numbers into a text list using Python. This is my code

```
import hashlib
def SHA1_hash(string):
    hash_obj = hashlib.sha1(string.encode())
    return(hash_obj.hexdigest())

with open("/Users/admin/Downloads/Project_files/dictionary.txt") as f:
    n = 5
    numtext_list = []
    for i in range(0,n+1):
        for j in f:
            numtext = j.strip() + str(i)
            numtext_list.append(numtext)
    print(numtext_list)
```

However, it only concatenates the first number (which is 0) to the file elements, and the output list is like this:

```
'yellow0', 'four0', 'woods0', 'hanging0', 'marching0', 'looking0', 'rouse0', 'lord0', 'sagde0', 'meadows0', 'sinking0', 'foul0', 'bringing0', 'disturb0', 'uttering0', 'scholar0', 'wooden0'
```

While I want it to also have

```
'yellow1', 'yellow2', 'yellow3', 'yellow4', 'yellow5','four0',...
```

as well as other combinations of text and numbers to the list.

Please help me with this, I'm totally new to Python so please excuse me if this is not a good question or I am wrong in writing keywords, thank you so much.

Comment: Can you provide the content of `dictionary.txt`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first time you do `for j in f:` you read the entire file. So when you get to the next iteration of the `for i` loop, there's nothing left to read, so the inner loop ends immediately and nothing is appended.

Swap the order of your loops so you only have to read the file once.

```
for j in f:
    word = j.strip()
    for i in range(0, n+1):
        numtext = f'{j}{i}'
        numlist.append(numtext)
```

Other possible solutions:

1. Read the file into a list with `f.readlines()` and then loop over that.
2. Put `f.seek(0)` before each `for j in f:` loop.

Comment: Hello, thank you so much for the clear answer. I realized where my problem is. However, when I tried to run the code as your suggestion, the output is like this: 'writing\n0', 'writing\n1',...
How can I remove the '\n'? I tried to use strip(\n) but it did not work.